# 2 different services for same DaemonSet K8s

Tags: kubernetes, service, openshift, daemonset

I was wondering if there is a way to create a service for a pod on a specific node.
For example:

Lets say I have a cluster with 4 worker nodes [compute-0 ... compute-3].

Nodes "compute-0" and "compute-1" have a label "app=firstApplication"

Nodes "compute-2" and "compute-3" have a different label "app=secondApplication"

I have a single Daemonset running across all 4 nodes.

I want to create 2 services, one for each couple of nodes.
Is this possible somehow?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The reason for what we are trying to do is that we have an Openshift4.6 cluster, and for security reasons we have VXLAN port blocked off between 2 groups of nodes. When pods try to resolve DNS queries using the default dns service (172.30.0.10), sometimes they access the dns pods on the blocked off nodes.

Answer (score 1):

**No - this is not possible!** Since services are referencing their Pods by Labels and all Pods in a DaemonSet are labelled the same, you can't do that. Of course, you could label your Pods after creation, but since this would be lost after recreation of the DaemonSet, I would not go down that route.

You could split your DaemonSet into parts and use [Node Selectors or Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#running-pods-on-select-nodes) to control the distribution of Pods over Nodes.

> If you specify a .spec.template.spec.nodeSelector, then the DaemonSet controller will create Pods on nodes which match that node selector. Likewise if you specify a .spec.template.spec.affinity, then DaemonSet controller will create Pods on nodes which match that node affinity.

That way, each DaemonSet can have its own Service.

Comment: I don't understand how `Taints and Tolerations` can solve the problem in question.

Comment: @Fritz i am affraid it's possible

Comment: The reason for what we are trying to do is that we have an Openshift4.6 cluster, and for security reasons we have VXLAN port blocked off between 2 groups of nodes. When pods try to resolve DNS queries using the default dns service (172.30.0.10), sometimes they access the dns pods on the blocked off nodes. Any idea as to how we can fix this? My current idea was to create 2 services for DNS pods (one fore each node group) and tell the pods to resolve queries via the specific services.

Comment: @LinuxDevops In that case, I recommend you create 2 Daemonsets and assign their Pods to your Nodes with affinity -> nodeAffinity -> requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution. I have amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia thinking about it, nodeSelector or affinity rules are the better tool. I have amended my answer accordingly, thanks!

Comment: @Linux Devops Is it possible for you to split your `DaemonSet` into two  `DaemonSets` (one for `"compute-0" & "compute-1"`  and one for `"compute-2" & "compute-3" `) as Fritz Duchardt suggested ?

Comment: This is the DNS operator daemonset,  which is managed by the operator, hence changing it's configuration is sadly impossible(unless you turn it to unmanaged, which is something we want to avoid).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to patch existing pods. Add those label in your pods. May be you need to handle another operator. The job of the operator is to get the pods first. Then check if the desire label exist or not . If not exist patch the label of the pod. this is just like `kubectl` patch. With the help of `kubeclient` just update the label if the label is not exist in the pods. do some research about kubeclient. There are also an example sample-controller in kubernetes. Here is the link :

[ref](https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-controller)

if there are some extra label in pod just add them in selector.

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: first-svc
  labels:
    app: firstApplication
spec:
  selector:
    app: firstApplication
  ports:
    - name: http 
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: second-svc
  labels:
    app: secondApplication
spec:
  selector:
    app: secondApplication
  ports:
    - name: http 
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
---
```

Comment: Sadly this is impossible, since it is the same DaemonSet and the pods have the same labels. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to bypass this somehow

Comment: it's not impossible. let me tell you how  you can add extra labels . you just need to patch existing pods. add those label in your pods. may be you need to handle another operator . do some research . there are also a example sample-controller in kubernetes. here is the link : [ref](https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-controller)

Comment: you can get some idea from there. you just need to put some effort.  just write a operator to patch labels.with  kubeclient i am pretty sure you can do that

Comment: We are trying to use k8s' features without writing custom operators

Comment: then i guess it's quite impossbile